# Combine multiple values into one cell in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, string-concatenation

I have a data set that can multiple rows with the same claim no. and different names:

```
   claim_id           name
    112               John Smith
    112               Tom Harris
    113               Randy Dugar
```

If the claim id is the same, then I need all the names to be in one row separated by a comma:

```
    claim_no          name
    112               John Smith, Tom Harris
    113               Randy Dugar
```

I've created something similar in T-SQL, but am new to Postgres.  I've tried something like the following, but I just get an error:

```
   with firstrun as(
   select distinct kia.claim_id as claim_id,  c.first_name ||' '  
   ||c.last_name as name
   from kia
   inner join
   claims c
   on kia.claim_id = c.claim_id


   )

   select distinct claim_id, substring((Select ',' || ' '|| fr.name as   text()]
   from firstrun fr
   for xml path('')), 2, 500)
```

Comment: Hint:  `string_agg()`.

Answer (score 4):

The `string_agg` aggregate function will do all the heavy lifting for you:

```
SELECT   claim_id, STRING_AGG(name, ', ')
FROM     claims
GROUP BY claim_id
```

Comment: This is great.  Never heard of that function before and it works perfectly.